# Subspaces and linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, banach-spaces

We assume that we have a space $D$, and $D_1$ is a subspace of $D$. Why there is a linear operator $L:D\to Y$ ($Y$ a suitable space) such that $D_1=\ker(L) $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show this using either of the following two methods:

Method 1:

> Let $B_1$ be a basis for the subspace $D_1$ of the vector space $D$. Then we can extend $B_1$ to a basis $B$ for $D$.

> Moreover, we can uniquely specify a linear mapping by specifying the image under that operator of each element of a basis of the domain space.

> Now let us define a mapping $T \colon D \longrightarrow D$ as follows:

> Let
> $$
> T(b) := \begin{cases} \mathbf{0} & \mbox{ if } b \in B_1 \\ b & \mbox{ if } b \in B - B_1. \end{cases} 
> $$

> Alternatively, each element $x \in D$ can be uniquely expressed as
> $$
> x = \alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m b_m + \alpha_{m+1} b_{m+1} + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n,
> $$
> where $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m, \alpha_{m+1}, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are scalars, $b_1, \ldots, b_m \in B_1$ and $b_{m+1}, \ldots, b_n \in B - B_1$. Note that $B \supseteq B_1$ by our construction. Now let us define
> $$
> T(x) := \alpha_{m+1} b_{m+1} + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n. 
> $$
> This $T$ is linear and $\ker T = D_1$.

Method 2:

> Let $D/D_1$ be the quotient space of $D$ by $D_1$, that is, let
> $$
> D/D_1 := \big\{ x + D_1 \colon x \in D \big\},
> $$
> where
> $$
> x + D_1 := \left\{ x+d_1 \colon d_1 \in D_1 \right\}. 
> $$
> This set $D/D_1$ is a vector space over the same field as $D$ under the opetation of addition and scalar multiplication defined as follows:
> $$
> \left( x+D_1 \right) + \left( y + D_1 \right) := (x + y ) + D_1
> $$
> for all $x, y \in D$ and
> $$
> \alpha \left( x + D_1 \right) := (\alpha x) + D_1
> $$
> for all $x \in D$ and scalars $\alpha$.
> The set $D_1 = \mathbf{0} + D_1$ is the zero vector in $D/D_1$.

> Now let $T \colon D \longrightarrow D/D_1$ be defined by
> $$
> T(x) := x + D_1.
> $$
> This $T$ is also linear with $\ker T = D_1$.

Comment: Thanks!, I think the second method is more useful than the first, bcause we often work with Infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @HiddaWalid I think even method 1 is applicable in the case of infinite-dimensional vector spaces.